# flask redirect() gives 400 Bad Request if port 443

Tags: ssl, nginx, flask, http-redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am deploying a flask app on a Centos7 server, the application is launched by [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) on `localhost:8000` through:
`venv/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 -w 4 microblog:app`

This port is then forwarded to 443 through nginx (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/microblog.conf`):

```
server {
    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;

    # location of the self-signed SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate /home/cocchi/git_dir/covid20/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/cocchi/git_dir/covid20/certs/key.pem;

    # write access and error logs to /var/log
    access_log /var/log/covid20_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/covid20_error.log;

    location / {
        absolute_redirect off;
        port_in_redirect off;
        # forward application requests to the gunicorn server
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        # handle static files directly, without forwarding to the application
        alias /home/cocchi/git_dir/covid20/app/static;
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

and here the general conf file for nginx `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` :

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
#    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    default_type        text/html;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            absolute_redirect off;
            port_in_redirect off;
            server_name_in_redirect off;
            # redirect any requests to the same URL but on https
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.

#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

#        location / {
#        }

#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }

#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

My problem is that every time I have a `redirect()` in the flask app it gives me this error:

> 400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

And I cannot figure out how to solve it!
I read that `redirect()` does not respect http/https in [this post](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/773), but I don't get how to configure it to make it works on my machine.

The port is forwarded to the outside world to port `4343` by the network administrator, and the problem is that I lost this specific port `4343` every time I have a `redirect()` in my code...

Any help is much appreciated!!!